# prevent zfs storage driver in docker rootless mode

Tags: docker, zfs

I'm trying to use rootless docker, but when pulling and image, docker is trying to use zfs as the storage driver. I can confirm that `docker info` shows the zfs driver. I didn't intend or configure that anywhere. My OS isn't defaulted to zfs (btrfs the the root, boot etc). My home directory is in a mounted zfs.

The instructions for [zfs in docker](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/zfs-driver/) explains how to use the daemon.json to set the storage driver. However, it doesn't exist for me, which is expected, but I see no equivalent config in my system that does so. The ~/.docker/config.json has nothing about storage drivers.

Is the fact that my home directory (and the rootless docker directories) are in a mounted zfs location enough to force that as the storage driver? Is there any way to have rootless docker use a different storage driver, maybe by pointing my rootless install to another location that isn't a zfs backed directory?

Comment: for others to find this easier, this is the docker / zfs error:
`docker: failed to register layer: exit status 1: "/sbin/zfs fs create -o mountpoint`

(People see similar errors for docker for other permission issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed that moving the location of ~/.local/share/docker was enough to stop using the zfs storage driver. I made that directly into a soft link to /var/docker_rootless, and all worked. Even `docker info` reports using the overlay2 storage driver now.

notes on exact steps to resolve:

1. stopped docker service first.

- `systemctl --user stop docker.service`

2. also made /var/docker_rootless owned by my user that is running rootless docker.

- `sudo mkdir /var/mynewdir; sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) /var/mynewdir`

3. moved the original docker folder

- `mv ~/.local/share/docker ~/.local/share/docker.bak`

4. created the link

- ln -s /var/mynewdir ~/.local/share/docker

5. Coppied the old folder contents to the new directory.

- `rsync -A ~/.local/share/docker.bak/ ~/.local/share/docker`